# Explanation How Rectangle Recursion JavaScript works

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I am a beginner in code world. I have troubles understanding recursion in JavaScript especially when it needs two or more looping. Like I want to print rectangle using recursion. I don't know completely how to make a base case, condition when it still executed. For examples, these codes below I use to print rectangle or holey rectangle.

```
function box(num) {
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let str = ''
    for (let j = 0; j < num; j++) {
      str += '*'
    }
    console.log(str)
  }
}

box(5)


function holeBox (num) {
   for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    let str = ''
     for(let j = 0; j < num; j++){
        if(i == 0 || i == num -1 || j == 0 || j == num - 1) {
          str += '*'
        } else {
           str += ' '
        }
     }
     console.log(str)
   }
}

holeBox (5)
```

Please help me to understand recursion, an explanation would be great. My goals are not only to solve those codes but also to understand how recursion works. I've searched there's no good source to learn recursion, or I just too dumb to understand. Thanks in advance

Comment: Recursion is used to solve big problem by reduce it to smaller problem until it easy to solve. Your rectangle can not be transform into that (I guess it can but will be very not straight forward)

Comment: I think all of pattern that I can use looping can be solved with recursion. Any idea where I can learn more about recursion by example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even your box code can be turn into recursion but I don't think it will help you understand the concept of recursion.

If you really have to:

```
function getBox(arr, size) {
    let length = arr.length;
    if (length == size)
        return arr; // recursion stop rule - if the size reached
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
        arr[i].push("*"); // fill new size for all row
    arr.push(new Array(length + 1).fill("*")); // add new row
    return getBox(arr, size); // recursive call with arr bigger in 1 row
}
```

However, I believe @Gumbo answer explain the concept better then this...

Comment: thanks, but when I tried to execute your codes, there's error ? arr is the error ?

Comment: @AndyWarhol what do you means? what error do you get? I run it locally without any error... Notice to call it with empty array as `let box = getBox([], 5);`

Comment: my bad.. sorry, so david we need an array to do it ? why ?

Comment: @AndyWarhol Recursion is solving small problem in order to solve bigger ones. In this case - drawing box of 1X1 if you have empty array is easy. If you gets bigger size then you start from the smallest array (size 0) and start building your box up to size `n`

Comment: thanks. is there any problem or code that I learn ? or do you have materials or good sources for me to learn. recursion is way too hard to me as a beginner in code world.

Comment: @AndyWarhol Don't remember any great resources to learn recursion - but I guess you can start with learning it by doing sort (merge sort for example)

Answer (score 2):

To understand how recursion works, just think of how you can split up what you want to accomplish into smaller tasks, and how the function can complete one of those tasks, and then call itself to do the next- and so on until it is finished. I personally don't think printing boxes is the best way to learn recursion, so imagine you wanted to search an array for a specific value; ignore JavaScript's `indexOf()/find()` functions or similar for now.

To do this using loops, its easy, just iterate over the array, and check every value:

```
//Returns the index of the first occurrence of a value in an array, or -1 if nothing is found
function search(needle, haystack) {
    for (let i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Doing this using recursion is easy as well:

```
function recursiveSearch(needle, haystack, i) {
    if (i > (haystack.length - 1)) return -1; //check if we are at the end of the array
    if (haystack[i] == needle) return i; //check if we've found what we're looking for

    //if we haven't found the value yet and we're not at the end of the array, call this function to look at the next element
    return recursiveSearch(needle, haystack, i + 1);
}
```

These functions do the same thing, just differently. In the recursive function, the two if statements are the base cases. The function:

1. Tests if the current element is out of bounds of the array (meaning we've already searched every element), and if so, returns -1
2. Tests if the current element is what we're looking for, and if so, returns the index
3. If neither of the statements above apply, we call this function recursively to check the next element
4. Repeat this until one of the base cases kicks in.

Note that recursive functions are usually called from other helper functions so that you don't have to pass the initial parameters to call the function. For example, the `recursiveSearch()` function above would be private, and it would be called by another function like this:

```
function search(needle, haystack) {
    return recursiveSearch(needle, haystack, 0);
}
```

so that we don't have to include the third parameter when we call it, thus decreasing confusion.

Comment: I have a question for you. Is any code that using loop can be converted to recursion  or not? If yes, mind to explain me how to convert nested loop. Thanks